# Easiest way to ignore blank lines when reading a file in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have some code that reads a file of names and creates a list:

```
let who-file-name "world-health-field-surveillance.csv"
let who-file-name-dict csv:from-file who-file-name
let who-file-names sort [who] of names
let index 1 ;not 0, this removes the header in the csv

repeat length who-file-names [
  file-open "world-health-field-surveillance.csv"
  if file-at-end? [stop]
  let entry (item 0 (item index who-file-name-dict))
  if entry = "\n" [stop]
```

The file might end with some blank lines or its possible the file has names separated by a newline, like so:

```
Allman
Atkinson

Behlendorf
```

#### I want to ignore any lines that contain only whitespace.

My sample code doesn't work. 
How could I do this in netlogo?

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do, exactly? If I have a csv file that looks like this:

[image]

If I run this code:

```
extensions [ csv ]

to setup
  ca
  let example csv:from-file "example_names.csv"
  print example
  reset-ticks
end
```

I get a list output that looks like:

```
[[Allman] [Atkinson] [Behlendorf] [Belnich] [Cravit] [Court]]
```

Is that not what you're after? If you need just a single-level list, you can do

```
print reduce sentence example
```

to get

```
[Allman Atkinson Behlendorf Belnich Cravit Court]
```