# How can I open the same file twice in Netlogo? (Two file pointers)

Tags: netlogo

I would like to open the same file twice. In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51332183/635160) I am trying to check to see if the file contains blank lines.

I have some POC code to answer that question, but it requires the same file to be open twice.

```
    let who-file-name "world-health-field-surveillance.csv"
    let who-file-name-dict csv:from-file who-file-name
    let who-file-names sort [who] of names
    let index 1 ;not 0, this removes the header in the csv

    repeat length who-file-names [
      file-open "world-health-field-surveillance.csv"
      while [ not file-at-end? ][
         let row csv:from-row file-read-line
         if (not empty? row) [
            ask names (item (index - 1) who-file-names) [
                set label item 0 (item index who-file-name-dict)
```

The `file-read-line` function is from Netlogo's `csv` [extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html).

The issue is that netlogo's `file-open` function is used to specific which file is being referenced to in subsequent code.

The line `let row csv:from-row file-read-line` will advance the file pointer and  discard  the row, which would normally be read in by the line `who-file-names`.

What should I do? This seems to be a limitation of netlogo. But I might be able to avoid this issue somehow.

Comment: The first thing that pops into my head is to separate out the operations - open the file, read everything into a string or list of strings as appropriate, then re-open the file to process it as needed, using the stored data as reference.  If your file is very large, this might not be practical.